# QT C++ работа с базой данных в разных потоках

Tags: c++, qt

Как можно модифицировать ПО для мультипоточной работы.

Хотелось бы увидеть минимальный базовый пример, дабы разобраться и пока не лезть в дебри.

**Есть большая таблица(100 тыс наименований) при их запросе виснет GUI.
Хотелось бы это устранить.**

Логика была такая.

1. Человек открывает программу.
2. Конструктор формы отправил запрос потоку в БД.
3. Строится каркас приложения.
4. Берём данные из потока в основной.
5. Заполняем полученными данными таблицу.

p.s
Пробовал сделать подобное на сигналах и слотах с применением QThread. Отправлял запрос в другой поток, но он начинал работать только когда закроется основное приложение...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**mainwindow.СPP**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //QSqlDatabase objDatabase;
    objDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    objDatabase.setDatabaseName("librarydb");
    objDatabase.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    objDatabase.setPort(3306);
    objDatabase.setUserName("hays0503");
    objDatabase.setPassword("hays0503");
    objDatabase.open();

    //QSqlTableModel *objTableModel;
    objTableModel = new QSqlTableModel();
    objTableModel->setTable("author");
    if (!objTableModel->select())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Error";
    }else {
       ui->tableView->setModel(objTableModel);
    }
}
```

**mainwindow.H**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QSql>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlTableModel>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSqlDatabase objDatabase;
    QSqlTableModel *objTableModel;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFuture<QSqlTableModel*> future = QtConcurrent::run(
        [this]() 
        {
            // Исполняем этот код в другом потоке

            //QSqlDatabase objDatabase;
            objDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
            objDatabase.setDatabaseName("librarydb");
            objDatabase.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
            objDatabase.setPort(3306);
            objDatabase.setUserName("hays0503");
            objDatabase.setPassword("hays0503");
            objDatabase.open();

            //QSqlTableModel *objTableModel;
            objTableModel = new QSqlTableModel(this);
            objTableModel->setTable("author");        
            if (!objTableModel->select())
            {
                delete objTableModel;
                objTableModel = nullptr;
                qDebug()<<"Error";
            }
            return objTableModel;
        });
    QFutureWatcher<QSqlTableModel*> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<QSqlTableModel*>(this);
    connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), watcher, 
        [this, watcher]()
        {
            // Запускаем этот код в UI потоке, когда объект future завершит свою работу в рабочем потоке
            ui->tableView->setModel(watcher->result());
            watcher->deleteLater(); // Удалим ненужный watcher
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    );
     watcher->setFuture(future); // Связываем watcher с feature. Это быстрая операция и не тормозит поток UI
}
```

Если много раз кликать на кнопку, то будет запущено сразу много одинаковых задач. 
Надо не забывать, что работать с объектами objDatabase и objTableModel можно только из одного потока одновременно.

Comment: Да, я слышал об этом Qt-вская ахритектура SQL работает строго на один поток(где создали там и работаем) и большие ограничение на манипуляции с данных.

Comment: Словил ошибку при подключение сигнал\слотов в лямбда выражение. Сode:https://pastebin.com/0Gq8mpj0  CodeError: https://pastebin.com/tF3pngt4. IMG: https://ibb.co/VW0LmtX