# Qt работа с потоками и данными

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

**Проблема**

Не могу передать данные выделенные в другом потоке через указатель в основной поток программы для того чтобы заполнить ComboBox.

Для многопоточности использую **QFuture / QtConcurrent::run / QFutureWatcher**

Пробовал через QSharedPointer но без результативно ссылка корректная но данных по ней нет.

[Github проекта](https://github.com/hays0503/Library/tree/dev)

[image: План]
[image: Программа]

**Database.cpp**

```
bool DataBase::setComboBox(
                    QComboBox *ComboBoxView,
                    QString TableName,
                    qint32 ColumTable,
                    QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel> &Table)
{

    QFuture<QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel>> future = QtConcurrent::run(
        [this,TableName]()
        {
            objDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
            objDatabase.setDatabaseName("librarydb");
            objDatabase.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
            objDatabase.setPort(3306);
            objDatabase.setUserName("hays0503");
            objDatabase.setPassword("hays0503");
            objDatabase.open();

            QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel> p_Table =
            QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel>(new QSqlTableModel);

            p_Table ->setTable(TableName);
            p_Table ->select();
            return p_Table;
         });

    QFutureWatcher<QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel>> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel>>(this);
    connect(watcher,&QFutureWatcherBase::finished,[watcher,ComboBoxView,ColumTable,&Table]() mutable
    {// Запускаем этот код в UI потоке, когда объект future завершит свою работу в рабочем потоке
        QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel> Tables = watcher->result();
        Table = Tables;
        ComboBoxView->setModel(Table.data());
        ComboBoxView->setModelColumn(ColumTable);
        ComboBoxView->showPopup();
        //watcher->deleteLater(); // Удалим ненужный watcher
    });
    watcher->setFuture(future); // Связываем watcher с feature. Это быстрая операция и не тормозит поток UI
    return true;

}
```

**DialogSearch.cpp** Метод инициализации элемента ComboBox

```
void DialogSearch::InitComboBox(
                  DataBase *p_connect, //Ссылка на базу данных
                  QComboBox *comboBox, //Ссылка на иницализируемый м
                  QString table_name, //Название таблицы в БД
                  qint32 row, //Номер колонки в таблице
                  QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel> &Table) // Попытка взять адрес выделенной памяти в потоке.
{
    ui->progressBar->setValue(20);
    p_connect->setComboBox(comboBox,table_name,row,Table);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(40);
    comboBox->setMaxVisibleItems(15);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(60);
    comboBox->setEditable(true);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(80);
}
```

**DialogSearch.cpp** Метод переключения tabWidget'ов.

```
void DialogSearch::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index)
{
    //Определенны в DialogSearch.h
    //QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel> p_Table_genre; 
    //QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel> p_Table_author;
    ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
    switch (index) {
    case 1: if(!completeWorkComboBox[0]){// Работали ли мы с ним до этого ?
    // Если нет то работаем иначе берём данные с прошлого раза
            InitComboBox(p_connect,
                         ui->comboBox_genre,
                         "genre",
                         1,p_Table_genre);}
            else{
            ui->comboBox_genre->setModel(p_Table_genre.data());// <--- Ссылка правильная но данных в ней нет из другого потока.
            ui->comboBox_genre->setModelColumn(1);
            }break;
    case 2: if(!completeWorkComboBox[1]){
            InitComboBox(p_connect,
                         ui->comboBox_author,
                         "author",
                         1,p_Table_author);}
            else{
            ui->comboBox_author->setModel(p_Table_author.data());//<--- Ссылка правильная но данных в ней нет из другого потока.
            ui->comboBox_author->setModelColumn(1);
            }
        break;

        if(!completeWorkComboBox[index-1])//Выполнили работу ? 
           completeWorkComboBox[index-1] = true;
        ui->progressBar->setValue(100);
}
```

Comment: Нарисовано аж три картинки - а что происходит в реальности - не понятно. Запрос к базе выполняется в фоновом потоке? Колбэк при завершении выполняется в основном потоке? Что там за ссылка на `Table`? Форматирование в коде - просто жесть.

Comment: @VTT Запрос к базе выполняется в отдельном потоке порождаемый основным потоком всё работа с потоками происходит в setComboBox.
Table ну это попытка взять данные из кучи выделенные в момент работы из другого потока.
А ссылка вида QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel>

Comment: Добавил ссылку на Github https://github.com/hays0503/Library/tree/dev

Comment: Так эти фрагменты выполняются или нет? Пример следует [сделать минимальным и приводить в самом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @VTT Да выполняются проблема в том что после того как я выделил данные из кучи я не могу их использовать в др потоке. Воспроизвести можно без проблем(разве что бд нужно) для этих целей я разместил ссылку на github.

Comment: Если это действительно сложно для восприятия я перепишу вопрос.

Comment: Так а какое значение оказывается в `QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel> Tables = watcher->result();`?

Comment: watcher->result(); Возражает ссылку на  QSqlTableModel выполненную в другом потоке там где собственно проходит ресурсоёмкая по времени часть(запрос в базу данных).

Comment: `watcher->result();` возвращает не ссылку, а экземпляр объекта `QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel>`. А я спрашиваю про конкретное значение возвращенного объекта.

Comment: Цель была такая один раз выполнить работу после уже использовать эти данные. Но конкретно это у меня не удавалась данные выделенные из кучи пропадали.
 Стоп выходит если он возвращает экземпляр watcher->result();  то по ссылке он его не передаст т.к данные локальные для него?!

Comment: Цель была оптимизировать запросы.
Загрузить данные из бд один раз и пользоваться ими в дальнейшем.

Comment: Еще раз: какое значение оказывается в `QSharedPointer<QSqlTableModel> Tables = watcher->result();`? Не тип значения, не цель возврата, не название переменной, а конкретное значение?

Comment: А ну там адрес...
Вот скрин если я правильно вас понял.
https://i.imgur.com/RjnJKG8.png

Comment: Ну значит все нормально передалось.

Comment: Да передалось но когда она выходит из потока данные пропадают .

Comment: Кто выходит из потока?  Вы же сами написали *"Запускаем этот код в UI потоке"*. Где данные пропадают? Вы же только что сами выяснили, что данные на месте. Короче говоря, без минимального примера, демонстрирующего данную проблему (если она действительно имеет место), вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: Вот это и есть по сути минимально базовый пример на основе него и строилось. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/938378/qt-c-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Пример **должен демонстрировать проблему**.

Comment: @VTT Хорошо завтра перепишу пример c проблемой и выложу его сюда.
Дабы его можно было скомпилировать и запустить.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась.

Заключалась в связи ***Поток<--->База данных***.

Проще говоря если создать подключение в другом потоке и получить потом ссылку на результирующие данные(`QFutureWatcher->result();`) , которые связаны через модели по типу (`QSqlTableModel/QSqlQueryModel`) то у вас **не будет доступа к подключению а следственно и к данным**.

Решение проблемы: заключается в создание **подключения за приделами потока** там где в дальнейшем понадобятся они.

Пример.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QFuture>
#include <QFutureWatcher>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QtConcurrent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    objDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    objDatabase.setDatabaseName("librarydb");
    objDatabase.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    objDatabase.setPort(3306);
    objDatabase.setUserName("hays0503");
    objDatabase.setPassword("hays0503");
    objDatabase.open();

}

void MainWindow::LoadTable(QString query)
{
    QFuture<QSqlQueryModel*> future = QtConcurrent::run(
        [this,query]()
        {
            // Исполняем этот код в другом потоке


            //QSqlTableModel *objTableModel;
            objQuery = new QSqlQueryModel(nullptr);
            objQuery->setQuery(query,objDatabase);
            ui->tableView->setModel(objQuery);
            ui->tableView->update();
            ui->tableView->show();

            return objQuery;
        });
    QFutureWatcher<QSqlQueryModel*> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<QSqlQueryModel*>(this);
    connect(watcher,&QFutureWatcherBase::finished,[this, watcher]()
    {// Запускаем этот код в UI потоке, когда объект future завершит свою работу в рабочем потоке
        pointer = watcher->result();
        ui->tableView->setModel(pointer);
        watcher->deleteLater(); // Удалим ненужный watcher
    });
     watcher->setFuture(future); // Связываем watcher с feature. Это быстрая операция и не тормозит поток UI
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //Долгий и тяжёлый запрос
    QString query =
  "   SELECT \n\
                `books`.id_books, \n\
                `books`.name_book, \n\
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `author`.author_record), \n\
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `genre`.genre_record), \n\
                `bbk`.bbk_record, \n\
                `udc`.udc_record, \n\
                `books`.isbn, \n\
                `publisher`.publisher_record, \n\
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `book_binding_type`.binding_type), \n\
                `books`.description_record \n\
      FROM \n\
                `books` \n\
                    JOIN \n\
                `author_join_table` ON `author_join_table`.id_books = `books`.id_books \n\
                    JOIN \n\
                `author` ON `author`.id_author = `author_join_table`.id_author \n\
                    JOIN \n\
                `genre_join_table` ON `genre_join_table`.id_books = `books`.id_books \n\
                    JOIN \n\
                `genre` ON `genre`.id_genre = `genre_join_table`.id_genre \n\
                    JOIN    \n\
                `book_binding_type` ON `book_binding_type`.id_book_binding_type = `books`.index_book_binding_type \n\
                    JOIN \n\
                `publisher` ON `publisher`.id_publisher = `books`.index_publisher \n\
                    JOIN \n\
                `udc` ON `udc`.id_udc = `books`.index_udc \n\
                    JOIN \n\
                `bbk` ON `bbk`.id_bbk = `books`.index_bbk \n\
      GROUP BY `books`.id_books;";

    LoadTable(query);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString query =
        "SELECT * FROM librarydb.bbk;";

    LoadTable(query);

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    ui->tableView_2->setModel(pointer);
    pointer_1 = pointer;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    ui->tableView->setModel(pointer_1);
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QSql>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlTableModel>



namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void LoadTable(QString query);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:


private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();


    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_4_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSqlDatabase objDatabase;
    QSqlQueryModel *objQuery;
    QSqlQueryModel* pointer;
    QSqlQueryModel* pointer_1;


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```